# DATES with awk in UNIX

Tags: bash, date, unix, awk

I want to take two dates as argument from the user ( )  with

```
$./tool.sh --born-since <dateA> --born-until <dateB>
```

and from a file print the lines that are between those two dates.For example:

```
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Há»“ ChÃ­|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
```

So , i use awk command like this :

```
 awk  -F'|' '{print $4} [ file ... ]
```

to take the dates .. how can i use awk to make the dates from the txt to seconds form ?

Answer (score 2):

if the date variables are in the same format, you can convert everything to numbers and use comparison.

```
awk  -F'|' -v from=$dateA -v to=$dateB '{gsub("-","",$5); 
          gsub("-","",from); gsub("-","",to)} 
          from <= $5 && $5 <= to' file
```

Note, it's the fifth field in your file.

Comment: ok i understand your point, but how will i print the whole line after the comparison ?

Comment: that's it. it will print the line that satisfies the condition by default.  Fixed the date variable names.

Comment: i have this code:
`dateA= date -d "$2" +%Y%m%d
dateB= date -d "$4" +%Y%m%d
awk  -F'|' -v from=$dateA -v to=$dateB '{gsub("-","",$5); 
          gsub("-","",dateA); gsub("-","",dateB)} 
          from <= $5 && $5 <= to' persons.dat.txt`

but when i run the script it just prints the dateA and dateB

Comment: My bad, mixed up variable names, should use awk variables in the code from, to.  fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can either call the `/bin/date +"%s" --date="DATESTRING"` through `system()` if the DATESTRING matches a format "/bin/date" understands, or you use the internal mktime() function. But then you need to split your date according to awk(1):

```
   mktime(datespec)
             Turn  datespec  into  a time stamp of the same form as returned by systime(), and return the result.  The datespec is a string of
             the form YYYY MM DD HH MM SS[ DST].  The contents of the string are six or seven numbers representing respectively the full  year
             including century, the month from 1 to 12, the day of the month from 1 to 31, the hour of the day from 0 to 23, the minute from 0
             to 59, the second from 0 to 60, and an optional daylight saving flag.  The values of these numbers need not be within the  ranges
             specified;  for  example, an hour of -1 means 1 hour before midnight.  The origin-zero Gregorian calendar is assumed, with year 0
             preceding year 1 and year -1 preceding year 0.  The time is assumed to be in the local timezone.  If the daylight saving flag  is
             positive,  the time is assumed to be daylight saving time; if zero, the time is assumed to be standard time; and if negative (the
             default), mktime() attempts to determine whether daylight saving time is in effect for the specified time.  If datespec does  not
             contain enough elements or if the resulting time is out of range, mktime() returns -1.
```

So you need to prepare your date fields to use the form given in the documentation.

```
split($5, D, "-");
DS = sprintf("%4d %2d %2d 00 00 00", D[1], D[2], D[3]);
T = mktime(DS);
```

should do the job.